# jQuery animate img inside li

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate the img `menu.png` using jQuery

I have tried both of these ways, but neither work.

```
$('#toggle').children().animate({left:'150px'},200)
$('li#toggle > img').animate({left:'150px'},200)
```

my html:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="toggle"><img src="png/menu.png"/></li>
    <li><a href="#1"><img src="png/dwelling1.png"/> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2"><img src="png/help1.png"/> About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3"><img src="png/mail59.png"/> Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4"><img src="png/business.png"/> Other</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Does someone see an error?

**EDIT:** my updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc7hp3hx/2/). I made the img in the li have relative positioning as suggested by Scimonster.

Thank you

Comment: Refrain from editing your question just to point out the solution. The answers are here for this purpose. Just mark the one that suits you as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine. The `left` is animated. You just can't see it, because it also needs CSS `position: relative`. Otherwise, it maintains its original position in the document.

CSS:

```css
.menu img {position: relative}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xc7hp3hx/1/

Comment: Please add the code change to your answer to make it clear to everyone. Also, when patching up the OP original code, try not to change the bits that are not related to the problem. Anyway, +1.